# Managing state iFrame Chrome Extension with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am having some trouble finding the best solution to a problem I am having.

Currently I have an extension that inserts itself in to the page as an iFrame, at the moment when I make a change on one tab it updates on all tabs.

My question is, how do you guys manage state within chrome extensions built on a framework similar to react?

I can't quite wrap my head around this. Do I pass the TabID in to the iFrame? and if so how do you manage garbage collection and also is their an example of implementation.

If I could start a new instance I would some data to persist but this seems like a really bad way to do it.

I am using ReactJS with Redux.

Thank you.

Comment: See [Communicating Between Extension Components](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#solutions) wherein it mentioned that, to inject a content script from the DevTools page, you must retrieve the ID of the inspected window's tab using the [`inspectedWindow.tabId`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow#property-tabId) property and send a message to the background page. From the background page, call [`tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) to inject the script.

Comment: And, for additional insights, see this [blog post](https://developer.zendesk.com/blog/rendering-to-iframes-in-react).